# Last night I ____ (lost) my keys - can you help me look for them?

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

> A) Last night I ____ (*lost*) my keys - I had to look for them.
>   B) I ____ (*lost*) my keys - can you help me look for them?
>   C) Last night I ____ (lost) my keys - can you help me look for them?

I know that for question A we use Past Simple because we know the specific time the action was completed.

> **Answer A:** Last night I **lost** my keys - I had to look for them.

For question B we use Present Perfect Simple because the specific time the action was completed is not mentioned, and the consequence of the action is visible in the present moment.

> **Answer B:** I **have lost** my keys - can you help me look for them?

So! The question C is a combination of question A and B. What tense should we use?

Comment: You already answered it, didn't you?

Comment: My question is, what tense should I use in the last question because it is a combination of question A and B. So, this sentence has described the specific time the action was completed, as well as the consequence the action has in the present moment.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the simple past tense, *lost*. You know that the losing of the keys happened last night, and that's all that you need to know. Even if you haven't found them yet, it doesn't matter- you *lost* them last night.

(Fyi, also, when you ask "what tense should we use", you should not include the "to" - you should use the bare infinitive, without the "to", as I am doing in this sentence.)